# Href being set with " "Double Quotes" "?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I made a extension a while back for soundcloud for downloading cover art (To embed into mp3's to keep things looking good). It has always worked until the other day when suddenly my button no longer did anything. While trouble shooting I noticed this:

```
<a id="art_url" download="coverart" href=""https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000139319200-yw1j7g-t120x120.jpg"">Download Cover Art</a>
```

For some reason there are a extra set of quotes around the url of the cover art...

content.js

```
var url = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[9].style.backgroundImage;
var name = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[10].innerText;

url = url.split("url(")[1];
url = url.split(")")[0];

var data = [url, name];

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data); //sends array of url of cover art, and name of song
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( //receives message from content script
    function(data) {
        //console.log("Message successful");
        console.log(data[0]);
        //url
        document.getElementById("art_url").href = data[0];
        //name
        song_name = data[1];
    }
```

popup.html

```
<button id="button"><a id="art_url" download="coverart">Download Cover Art</a></button>
```

[Screenshot of the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6mJj.png)

I'm stumped, no idea what happened, it was working one day then another day with no changes made to the code it is now doing this.

Comment: Did you think of looking at the contents of `data[0]`, and seeing if that contains the quotes?

Comment: In the screenshot I posted ([link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/D6mJj.png)) You can see the console log at the bottom.. for some reason I assumed that when it logs it automatically surrounds it in quotes.. It has been a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image is being set as `url("now-this-is-quoted.jpg")`. It used to be set as `url(this-is-not-quoted.jpg)`. You need to update your parser.

Comment: Ahhhh, How did I miss that! Thank You! How come it's just now breaking though? Oh well..  Fixed now.

Comment: Either they changed the site (or css generation tool), or chrome added some CSS normalization. Are the quotes in the source code?